# Boost to use string literals?

Tags: c++, boost, string-literals

Our projects use C++03 not C++11. So the string literals feature is not available yet. I was wondering if Boost library has string literals feature?

Comment: User-defined literals is a change in the core language (+ library), you can't do the same exact thing with only a library and C++ < 11. (Apart from pre-processing the source and possible really dirty C pre-processor tricks(?))

Comment: A string literal is simply a quoted string: `"this is a string literal"`. They've been in C++ since time immemorial. This question must be about something else.

Comment: I mean raw string: `string s = R"FOO(C:\Windows\System32)FOO";` in C++11. The backslash has literal meaning here, not escape character.